# p value : Confusion in basics

Tags: statistics

If I have to test a hypothesis like:

\begin{align}
H_0:\mu\leq10\\H_1:\mu>10\\
Z_{1-p}=\dfrac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt n}
\end{align}
From which I get p-value and I make a comment about whether it makes sense to reject $H_0$.

What happens for double sided tests? $\mu=10,\mu\neq10$.

Do I simply take $2\times p$ from the above and then make comments?

If yes, why are we doing that?

Comment: Yes. Ours is not to question why, ours is but to do or die.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now for a more serious answer.

You are correct that you take $2p$ where $p$ is the value from a table of normal distributions. This value represents the area under the curve of one tail of the normal distribution. With a double sided test, we need the area under the curve of both tails and so multiply by 2.

Comment: But why assume that the area of the tails will be the same?

Comment: @Inquest Because a normal distribution is symmetric about the y-axis. That is we can *show* that the tails are the same from the definition of the normal distribution; it's not an assumption.

Comment: If we were doing a two-tailed test on non-normal data (I've heard such a thing exists :P ), the calculation would be less simple, right?

Comment: @BenMillwood yes.

Comment: So, how would I test $\sigma=10, \sigma\neq 10$ using chi-squared. (Two sided of course).

Comment: I'm rusty on chi-squared tests, so I can't answer that without some review. I'd suggest starting with googling for "chi-squared two-sided test".

Comment: Update: you may want to ask this on our sister site [Stats.SE]. In particular, I found [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22347/chi-squared-always-a-one-sided-test) there.